# Hide two specific divs while date picker not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below html code where I need to hide divs - canvas-holder-CT , callratediv when date pickers range not selected.

**Code**

```
<span style="float: left;margin-left:2em"> <b>Date Range: </b>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" > <b>to </b>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker2"> </span><div id = "Alert" style="float:left;margin-left:2em"> Please select a valid Date Range!</div>
        </br>

    <div id="contain">
    <div id="canvas-holder" style="width:46%;float:left;position: absolute; left: 0px;  top: 100px;">
        <canvas id="chart-area" width="350" height="450"  style="display: block; margin-left:2em">      
    </canvas>
    <center> <b><details>
  <summary>Distribution by Hooks</summary>
</details></center> </b></div>

    <div id="canvas-holder-keymsg" style="width:46%;float:right;position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 100px;">
        <canvas id="chart-area-km" width="350" height="450" style="display: block; margin-left:2em">
    </canvas><center> <b><details>
  <summary>Distribution by Keymessages</summary>
</details></center> </b></div>

<div id="canvas-holder-CT" style="width:46%;float:right;position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 700px;">
        <canvas id="chart-area-CT" width="350" height="450" style="display: block; margin-left:2em">
        </canvas><center> <b><details>
  <summary>Distribution by Call Types</summary>
</details> </b></center></div>

<div id="callratediv" style="float:right; width: 46%;position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 1000px;">
<table id="CallTable" class="dataTable" align="center" style="float:right; width: 80%; height: 100px; ">
    <caption> <b>Call Rate </b></caption>
        <th id="CallNameLabel" style="text-align:center">Number of days in field</th>
        <th id="CallIdLabel" style="text-align:center">Number of calls submitted</th>   
        <th id="CallRateLabel" style="text-align:center">Call Rate </th>        
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
    </div>
```

Please find my script for JS.

```
 $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                onSelect: function() {
                    startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    start = formatDate(startDate);
                    if( start!=null && end!=null && end>=start)
                    {document.getElementById('Alert').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                    //document.getElementById('canvas-holder').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
                    //document.getElementById('canvas-holder-keymsg').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
                    //document.getElementById('canvas-holder-CT').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
                    document.getElementById('contain').style.visibility = 'visible';

                    initial(start, end);

                    }
                    else {
                   document.getElementById('Alert').style.visibility = 'visible'; //Will show
                //  document.getElementById('canvas-holder').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
                //  document.getElementById('canvas-holder-CT').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
                //  document.getElementById('canvas-holder-keymsg').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
                document.getElementById('contain').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
            //  $("callratediv").hide();
            //  $("canvas-holder-CT").hide();       
                    }
                }

            });
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
                onSelect: function() {
                    endDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    end = formatDate(endDate);
                    alert('skn here s' + startDate);
                    alert('skn here e' + endDate);
                    if( start!=null && end!=null && end>=start)
                    {document.getElementById('Alert').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                    //document.getElementById('canvas-holder').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
                //  document.getElementById('canvas-holder-keymsg').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
                //  document.getElementById('canvas-holder-CT').style.visibility = 'visible';
                    document.getElementById('contain').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
                    initial(start, end);
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('Alert').style.visibility = 'visible'; //Will show
                    //  document.getElementById('canvas-holder').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
                    //  document.getElementById('canvas-holder-CT').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
                    //  document.getElementById('canvas-holder-keymsg').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
                    document.getElementById('contain').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
                //  $("callratediv").hide();
                //  $("canvas-holder-CT").hide();                   
                              }
                    }

                });

            });
```

Unfortunately the code is working for divs - canvas-holder-keymsg , canvas-holder but not for the above mentioned ones.

Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many errors in your code. It's really hard to flag them all in an easy way for your to follow, but check these:

The ID selectors in jQuery require `#` before the ID. Change these lines:

```
$("callratediv").hide();
$("canvas-holder-CT").hide();
```

to:

```
$("#callratediv").hide();
$("#canvas-holder-CT").hide();
```

You have the above lines twice in your code, so fix both locations.

There is no `formatDate()` function in jQuery. Change these lines:

```
start = formatDate(startDate);
end = formatDate(endDate);
```

to:

```
start = $.datepicker.formatDate(startDate);
end = $.datepicker.formatDate(endDate);
```

Also there are errors about the variable `end` not being declared in the first half of the code, and the missing `initial()` function, but maybe you have those somewhere in your other code that you haven't posted.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$("#canvas-holder-CT")`. Selector for **jQuery** should be `#canvas-holder-CT`, not just **ID**.

Comment: Can you please put the lines here? I am not so good in Jquery.

Comment: contain div is already having all of those divs then why I don't know it is hiding  divs - canvas-holder-keymsg , canvas-holder but not canvas-holder-CT , callratediv